# Laravel Horizon worker : free memory usage

Tags: laravel, memory, horizon

We do have a Laravel horizon worker which loads tons of entities job after job always finishes crashing being Out of Memory.

Hence lots of Objects, Collections and normalized objets are created, but never discarded ..

Is there's a way to  ( flush | clear ) all entities at the end of one job so we do have a fresh memory footprint just like the once after initializing the app ?